# Show image when key is pressed with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to make a simple app that when a key is pressed on the users keyboard an image appears respective to that letter. I would like to do this for the entire alphabet (a, b, c...)

if a is pressed a.jpg shows up on my page, if r was pressed r.jpg would appear and so on.

I was going to do this with a mega list of if else statements only im sure there must be another way?

```
var ctrlPressed = false;
$(window).keydown(function(evt) {
  if (evt.which == 17) { // ctrl
    ctrlPressed = true;
      alert('sdf');
  }
})
```

Comment: Why is your example about the `ctrl` key, but the question about a-z keys? Are you asking how to map f.ex `ctrl+a`?

Comment: Instead of getting `keyCode`, I suggest you get value of it and combine with suffix like `key_value + ".jpg"`, it is simpler

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would go about doing this:

```
var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
letters = letters.split("");
//I'm lazy; you should define an array of letters

$(window).keydown(function(e){
    key = e.which - 65; //makes a-z = 1-27
    key = letters[key];
    $('img[src="' + key + '.jpg"]').show();
}
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64JZ4/)

**Source(s)**

[jQuery API - keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)
[jQuery API - Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)
[MDN - String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 0):

How about an array of image references where the index maps to the evt.which value

```
var images=[];
images[64]='a.jpg';
images[65]='b.jpg';
images[66]='c.jpg';
//...etc...

$(window).keydown(function(evt) {
    var image=images[evt.which]'
    if(image){
        alert(image);
    }
})
```

A bit ugly, probably not the most efficient, but easy to follow :)

Answer (score 0):

I would get the key value and then just match it again a-z. Try something like:

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();
    if(/[a-z]/i.test(key)) {
        alert(key+'.jpg');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BMZaF/

Answer (score 0):

Seems that event.which for letters corresponds to the ASCII value. So, you could do something like the following:

```
$(window).keydown(function(evt) {
  if (evt.which >= 65 && evt.which <= 90){
    $('img[src="' + String.fromCharCode(evt.which).toLowerCase() + '.jpg"]').show();        
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should named your image files with the alphabet KeyCodes.

For instance the entered letter "a" must be named "97.jpg".

So you can call it from your jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#input").bind('keypress', function (e) {
        console.log(e.which);  //or alert(e.which);  
        $("#Image").attr("src", e.which + ".jpg");
    });
});
```